# Twitter Bootstrap Button - Breaking background on hover

Tags: css, button, twitter-bootstrap, hover

I am using Twitter Bootstrap on one of my sites. I am having trouble with the buttons. The background of all the buttons break on hover - on one page. But works fine on other pages.

[Twitter button breaking on hover http://oi44.tinypic.com/wre2w5.jpg](http://oi44.tinypic.com/wre2w5.jpg)

Problem occurs in browsers like firefox, chrome and opera - but works fine on IE9

Addition 
Firebug css - Click on the link to view the image file - 
[Firebug css](http://gyazo.com/5eaafe334ae5b757dc6a3160da85b70d)

```
<div class="form-actions">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit-calculations">Submit</button>
<button type="reset" class="btn">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

OK I have added the code to a demo server. Click on the following link to view the working example. Link removed

Comment: Can you post some code please?

Comment: seems like you are out of blue ink...

Comment: @FrankPresenciaFandos What sort of code ? css from the firebug or the whole bootstrap css.

Comment: The one generating the buttons, how do you do it? Also, if you could replicate it in a small jsfiddle case, it'd be very helpful. Or a link to your site where we can see it live

Comment: @FrankPresenciaFandos I have added the code and a screenshot of the css from the firebug as well. Thanks

Comment: can you provide an example ? [this](http://jsfiddle.net/cangelis/kzAhF/) works fine on me.

Comment: @CanGeliş Working example link added to the original question. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are experiencing this issue it's because you have the following CSS (around line 273 of style.css):

```
.menu-toggle:hover,
button:hover,
input[type="submit"]:hover,
input[type="button"]:hover,
input[type="reset"]:hover,
article.post-password-required input[type=submit]:hover {
    color: #5e5e5e;
    background-color: #ebebeb;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #f9f9f9, #ebebeb);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #f9f9f9, #ebebeb);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f9f9f9, #ebebeb);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #f9f9f9, #ebebeb);
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, #f9f9f9, #ebebeb);
}
```

just remove it and everything should work as you expect.

***Addition by OP - to the above Answer***

Mark the following lines in bootstrap stylesheet as important

```
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #0088cc, #0044cc) !important;
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#0088cc), to(#0044cc)) !important;
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #0088cc, #0044cc) !important;
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #0088cc, #0044cc) !important;
background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #0088cc, #0044cc) !important;
```

Comment: Thankyou. You have pointed me to the solution. The bootstrap css applied to the plugin was conflicting with the css of the theme applied to the website. All I had to do now was to mark this line as important in my bootstrap stylesheet.
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #0088cc, #0044cc) !important;